# EPPLus in VB .net 2013

Tags: .net, vb.net, epplus

Do you have a example of how to work with EPPlus in VB.Net 2013?, Because I wrote an app following the instructions and it does not work. This is the code:

```
Imports System Imports System.IO 
Imports officeopenxml 
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim NewFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\control room abril.xlsx")
            Dim NewTemplate = New FileInfo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\control room abril.xlsx")
            Dim XlPackage = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(NewFile)
            Dim sheetDatos = XlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets("27 abril")
            Dim archivo As String
            archivo = sheetDatos.Cells(5, 2).Value
            MessageBox.Show(archivo)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please explain how it is not working. Do you get a compile error (if so, what error on what line)? Do you get a runtime exception (if so, what exception on what line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, except if the file path is wrong, or the path is correct but there is no sheet named `27 abril`